# Is there a way to fully automate torrent seeding without having to provide the torrent list myself?

Tags: bittorrent

I moved and finally I have a very fast fiber connection and I'd like to contribute to the torrent network. I'm searching for a way or tool, which automatically finds, downloads and seeds torrents - maybe at best also finds torrents in need for seeds.

At least it should be run by itself, I would put it on a mini-server and let it run as long as it can (fire and forget).

Comment: Unhealthy torrents typically cannot be healed because seeders are entirely absent and a complete copy cannot be retrieved.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That's true. With my intention there's maybe a slightly chance to get it fully and thus can seed further

Comment: you can probably cobble this together by combining a torrent client that picks up torrents from a directory with something that downloads torrents from a website, RSS feeds or the dht. you'll also need a lot of storage or eventually remove torrents once you have seeded to a certain ratio.